# Adding a redirect which is causing an infinite loop

Tags: regex, apache, redirect

I'm very unfamiliar with Apache and .htaccess files, but learning. Right now I'm running into an issue with a lot of sites where their old company page is

> domain.com/about-us

and it now needs to be

> domain.com/about-us/company

There are other pages that live under "about-us", so I need to signify that the redirect should only affect /about-us/ and not /about-us/etc. I'm seeing answers about using the dollar sign, but it feels very over my head. Does anyone know the easiest way to achieve this redirect without throwing the infinite loop?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have tried a variation of simple 301 Redirects (/about-us/ /about-us/company/, /about-us/$ /about-us/company/) and a few Rewrite rules, but I truly don't know what I'm doing and half of the code just throws a 500 error.

Comment: are you looking for a regex pattern to use for substituting?

Comment: Have you tried: `RewriteRule ^/about-us$ /about-us/company [R=301,L]`

Comment: @akash I'm really just trying to get it to work in any way possible. It's all pretty new to me, sadly.

Comment: @booboo - no dice :( Thank you though.